# Hours of Operation Status

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this little object that lets you know if a place is open based on two variables. However I would like to make this even better, because I am not very good at javascript I want to know what's best practice. How would I update open/close status in real-time for the user that gets there a minute before they close or open.

[CodePen Source](http://cdpn.io/EFwKl)

**html**

```
<h1 class="status"></h1>
<h2 class="hours"></h2>
```

**css**

```
body {
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.open   { background-color: #00a638; }
.closed { background-color: black; }
```

**js**

```
// variables
var open = "7:00";
var close = "5:00";

// setup miliary time
var mClose = close.replace(/:/g,'') + 1200;
var mOpen = open.replace(/:/g,'');

if (mOpen < 1000) {
  mOpen = "0" + mOpen;
}

// setup hours
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
if (hour >= 10) { mHour = hour; 
  } else { mHour = "0" + hour; }

// setup minutes
var minute = now.getMinutes();

if (minute < 10) {
  minute = "0" + minute;
}

var time = "" + mHour + minute;
console.log("Time is " + time);

// open/close status
if ((time >= mOpen) && (time < mClose)) {
 $("body").addClass("open");
 $(".status").html("Yes, We're Open");
} else {
 $("body").addClass("closed");   
 $(".status").html("Sorry We're Closed");
}

// display hours
$(".hours").html(open + " to " + close);
```

Comment: This doesn't need to be a jQuery plugin in order for lots of people to use it. Not everyone uses jQuery.

Comment: far, far too broad. There is no way this can be *"answered in a few paragraphs."*

Comment: I simplified my question, sorry I got a bit carried away with ideas there.

Comment: You can simply write a short function that checks the current time and change the 'open' to 'close' if required. You can call this function every minute with `window.setInterval`. On a sidenote, I don't really see why you aren't using `Date` for time comparisations and why you are using ambigious time identifiers.